# Convert 1 Line of PHP code to VB.NET

Tags: php, vb.net

I am trying to determine what this one line of code does in php so I can then convert it to VB.NET.

```
Code: $test = ("www.facebook.com" & "VSSLIGHTBOX007");
```

When I execute the following in php:

```
echo $test;
```

this returns: `VSS@A@DBOH #`

When I execute the follwing in vb.net:

```
test = ("www.facebook.com" And "VSSLIGHTBOX007")

Msgbox(test)
```

this returns: `ERROR`

Essentially, the result of the vb.net code should equal that of the php code.

What am I doing wrong?

I need to solve this ASAP. Please Help
Thanks.

Comment: Afaik, what you are doing in vb.net is equivalent to the php code (bitwise AND) so I guess it's not working because VB.NET doesn't like bitwise operations on strings?

Comment: As a side note: it is rare to perform bitwise operations on strings, make sure your original php code doesn't have a typo and actually meant to say &&.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP manual says that it bitwise AND's them together using ASCII encoding.

You will have to do this manually. Use the `Encoding` class to get each as an of ASCII bytes then bitwise AND them together.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "logically AND's them together using ASCII encoding"? In most languages I've worked with the `&` operator (`And` in VB.NET) performs a bitwise `and`.